# MS SQL соединить данные из разных строк одной таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица из которой нужно взять определенные значения из разных строк с сделать так чтобы в конечном итоге они были все одной строкой и по ним можно было сопоставить другие таблицы, ключевой столбец - Номер документа, документов много, в source code данные могут повторяться, ровно как и в остальных столбцах
Нужные данные находятся в разных строках одной таблицы и могут пересекаться с другими документами той же таблицы, возникают трудности в фильтрации и создании корректного запроса
Возможно ли с помощью запроса MS SQL сделать такой запрос не прибегая к языку программирования?
Фиолетовым отмечены данные которые нужно поставить в одну строку запросом, чтобы запрос отработал по всей таблице по бизнес ключу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли с помощью запроса MS SQL сделать такой запрос не прибегая к языку программирования?

Да, возможно. Для этого нужно использовать [оконные функции](https://habr.com/ru/post/268983/).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/726178)

Comment: Вопрос заключается не в том как сделать, а в том возможно/невозможно. Я ответил, что возможно и сослался на инструмент, с помощью которого можно это всё реализовать.